# Add new field 'message' for sending text message to specific address

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain, geth-debugging

I have created a private net following https://omarmetwally.blog/2017/07/25/how-to-create-a-private-ethereum-network/ holding 4 peers. I run Ethereum Block Explorer ( https://github.com/etherparty/explorer).

When I run Ethereum node, at the browser I could connect into the Ethereum Block Explorer from localhost:8000.

Transaction Details give :

```
Transactions - contained in current block
Transaction #1
Hash #  0x080af6ed6ecdf81a9af989a21e3a90f3379a84a1fc80ba7c656e1a8afd6e441c
From    0x5aff57c0d28d49fea39250293e0400d31947d226
To  0x9ecad548e91c02c8344654d13ef6ff075f096651
Gas 90000
Input   0x4d657373616765207375636365737366756c6c7920646973706c61796564
Value   "100000000000000000000"
```

I need to pass text message along with transaction. So I followed the command :

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x5aff57c0d28d49fea39250293e0400d31947d226', to:'0x9ecad548e91c02c8344654d13ef6ff075f096651', value: web3.toWei(100, "ether"),data:web3.toHex('Message successfully displayed')})
```

The 'message' is shown as hexa value in Input field. Can't a text message displayed in block explorer? Can a new field be added to hold text message?